# How to load an object inside another object using greenDAO?

Tags: android, greendao

I have these entities:

```
public class Category {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer color;
}

public class Item {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String groupType;
    private Category category;
}
```

How should I model greenDAO to have Category inside Item object?

**Edit:**

Generator Code:

```
public class GreenDaoGenerator {

    public static final String DEFAULT_PACKAGE = "xxxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1, DEFAULT_PACKAGE + ".entity");
        schema.setDefaultJavaPackageDao(DEFAULT_PACKAGE + ".dao");

        addCategory(schema);
        addItem(schema);

        DaoGenerator daoGenerator = new DaoGenerator();
        daoGenerator.generateAll(schema, "Generated Files");
    }

    private static void addItem(Schema schema) {
        Entity entity = schema.addEntity("Item");
        entity.addIdProperty();
        entity.addStringProperty("Name");
        entity.addStringProperty("GroupType");
        Property IdProperty = entity.addLongProperty("categoryId").getProperty();
        entity.addToOne(schema.getEntities().get(0), IdProperty);
    }

    private static void addCategory(Schema schema) {
        Entity entity = schema.addEntity("Category");
        entity.addIdProperty();
        entity.addStringProperty("Name");
        entity.addIntProperty("Color");
    }

}
```

I did it after your answer, please take a look if i'm doing it the right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [GreenDao Relations](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/), mapping `Item` entity to `Category` entity.

Here is an example (where `item` and `category` are entities in your greenDAO generator code):

```
Property IdProperty = item.addLongProperty("categoryId").getProperty();
item.addToOne(category, IdProperty);
```

Comment: I added the generator code after your comment, can you take a look and see if I'm doing it the right way, please. Thanks

Comment: Yes, your code looks right. After generation, `Item` entity will have a `Category` member with getter and setter.